# Difference between two atmospherically corrected Images

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat, envi, land-cover, atmospheric-correction

I corrected Landsat 5 image with two different methods, first atmospheric correction through calibration (means converting raw image into radiance), second atmospheric correction through QUAC atmospheric correction. The results I got are little bit change, the first one is a little brighter than the second one, so what is the difference between these two methods? and why my Image outputs are like that.

***Radiance Image***
[image]

***Output of QUACT atmospheric correction***
[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. I would recommend applying the atmospheric correction and plotting the spectral signatures, then post your results as an edit to your original question.

Comment: Ok Sure but I want to know the general concept which experts have about this.

Comment: Providing these figures will help you get better answers from the community. It should also become apparent how atmospheric scattering affects portions of the EM spectrum once you plot the results side be side.

Comment: Ok sure, I will do that.

Comment: @Aaron I edited this question as well sir.

Comment: I recommended plotting spectral signatures side by side rather than the corrected image. Please edit your question to include a single, focused question.

Comment: Now it's edited sir, kindly review it @Aaron