# Radiance and Raw Image difference after Radiometric calibration

Tags: qgis, remote-sensing, image, digital-image-processing, toa-calibration

I have done Radiometric calibration on Envi 5.3 and got the output of my input Landsat 5 image.
What is the difference between the **raw image** and the **radiance image** and why is this value of radiance called as
**TOA radiance**?

[image]

Figure 1: *Radiance Image*

[image]
Figure 2: *Raw Image*

Comment: Are these homework or test questions? https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/381177/8104

Comment: I am learning these on my own aspects, asking from experts will help me more in learning sir. Is this a policy of this SE that a person can't post more than one questions at a time sir?

Comment: Multiple, unique questions are encouraged.

Comment: @Aaron Sir now I edited the question, kindly look at that.

Comment: In practice, radiance is an interim step in preprocessing. The atmospherically corrected product that you want to use in your analysis is at-surface or at-sensor reflectance, not radiance. Normally, some type of atmospheric correction is applied in processing from DN to reflectance (eg., Chavaz COST method, dark object subtraction). I would strongly recommend finding a remote sensing of the environment textbook to help you in your learning objectives.

Answer (score 1):

The raw image is the image as it is captured by the sensor. What you have after the radiometric correction is a conversion of the raw values (also called digit number) into a physical value (the radiance, in other words the energy that is measured by the sensor. It is a calibration, i.e. the values are converted based on a usually simple mathematical transform (a first order linear transform) with known parameters (gain and offset provided in the metadata of the sensor). Therefore you would need more steps to get to the most useful information (the surface reflectance), which is the property of the observed materials (the proportion of sun light that is reflectected towards the sensor). The name TOA comes from Top Of Atmosphere, because at the calibration stage, you consider the radiance after it left the atmosphere, but if you want an accurate value of the surface reflectance you need to take the interferences with the atmosphere into account.